# how to stop function in python (telegram bot)

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I try to make selenium bot that integrate to telegram so i can start and stop easily

```
def mulai(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Absen Start!')
    while True:
        if pycron.is_now('*/1 * * * *'):
            absen()
        time.sleep(60)
```

but how to stop it?

Comment: Your code has syntax errors as indentation is crucial in Python, please fix them. Besides that, it seems the question is more about how to work with `while` loops, instead of Telegram Bot matter. Please read about how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the community to able to help you promptly.

Comment: If this is just a while loop question, the [wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) is a good place to start, and more thorough than some.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the code from running you can use the **break** statement in python.

```
from time import sleep

#Counting up to 10
for i in range(10):
    print(i+1)
    sleep(1)
    
    #stop counting at 5
    if i == 4:
        break
```

Without the break statement the code would continue counting up to 10.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i want is make another function to stop that function

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect your expected behaviour, then. It is important to set current _and_ expected behaviour, besides providing a full reproducible code. That is, if you use things from other modules, the imports must be shown, if you use global variables, they need to be defined, etc...

Comment: Sorry and thank you for your information this is my second time asking in this site, thank you for your reminder

Answer (score 0):

Based on clarification in comments, you are trying to stop one loop from elsewhere.  One approach is a shared variable:

```py
run_flag = True

def fn1():
    while run_flag:
        do_stuff()
        sleep(60)

def stop_fn1():
    global run_flag
    run_flag = False
```

This is safe so long as only one write access to `run_flag` can be made at any one time, i.e. you aren't trying to share it accross multiple threads.  If you *are* you need to look at using something thread safe, like a `semaphore`.

There is no need for `run_flag` to be global, as long it is can be accessed by both the looping function and the function which sets it.